# Unclear inequality in the proof of Birkhoff ergodic theorem.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to understand the tricky proof of the ergodic theorem (Birkhoff 1931). My reference is "Ward,Einsiedler - Ergodic theory (with a view towards number Theory)" section 1.6:

---

Consider the  sequence of functions 
$$a_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^i(x))$$
where $T$ is a measure preserving transformation and $f\in L^1_\mu$ (suppose real valued) . I've understand the part of the proof where it is proved that the pointwise limit $f^\ast $does exist but I've problems to show that $f^\ast\in L^1_\mu $. In particular, the following passage is obscure:

Lets define $g_n(x)=|a_n(x)|$, why it is true that 
$$\int g_n\,d\mu\le\int|f|\,d\mu$$

for every $n$?

(The rest of the proof follows by the Fatou's lemma)

Comment: Try the Triangle inequality and use invariance.

Comment: Use the fact that if $f$ is integrable and $T$ a measure preserving transformation then $f\circ T$ is integrable and $\int fd\mu = \int f\circ T d\mu$.

Comment: @Bebop, yes you are right. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the triangle inequality, 
$$\lVert a_n\rVert_1=\frac 1n\left\lVert\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^i\right\rVert_1\leqslant \frac 1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left\lVert f\circ T^i\right\rVert_1.$$
To conclude, notice that since $T$ is measure preserving, then 
$$\tag{*}\int g\mathrm d\mu=\int g \circ T\mathrm d\mu$$
for any $g$ which can be expressed as a linear combination of characteristic functions. 
By an approximation argument, we extend (*) to any integrable function $g$ and we conclude that 
$$\lVert a_n\rVert_1\leqslant \lVert f\rVert_1.$$